# Insert a complete list into a word document

Tags: list, document, document-template

I have a list and want to insert all of the rows into a word document. I've seen it's possible to insert fields from an individual row but can all rows be inserted in a single action.

Answer (score 1):

i dont quite understand where your comming from:

if you are not talking about code then:

1) goto the list in question

2) click on the list heading (title)

3) under actions select "edit in datasheet"

[image: datasheet 2007]

4) select all the rows and copy and paste into word

[image: datasheet]

for 2010

[image: datasheet]

1) click list or library in the menu above

2) select "Datasheet view"

4) select all the rows and copy and paste into word